# Angular 9: Custom directive to access value of child text input

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am working on an Angular 8 custom directive that I will use to conditionally append/remove HTML elements, apply CSS, etc, to a label and input field, both wrapped by a `div`

One of the conditions that I will be checking for is whether or not the input field contains text upon initialization. However, I can't figure out how to access the child input field's value. Even when I try to console.log the value in `ngAfterViewInit` , it displays as empty, rather than the correct "The sample text".

How can I access the input's value from the directive applied to the parent node?

The directive will be applied to numerous inputs, but all with the same structure below, where a `div` wraps the `label` and an `input` bound via `[(ngModel)]`.

I have a StackBlitz here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-odxwft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcollapsing-input.directive.ts)

HTML:

```
<div class='gs-input-field' appCollapsibleInput>
  <label for="gs-input-1">Label</label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='sampleText'>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  sampleText= 'Sample text'
}
```

Custom Directive

```
  import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  HostListener,
  AfterViewInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appCollapsibleInput]"
})

export class CollapsibleInputDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  rootEl;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //ref to the parent node
    this.rootEl = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    //ref to the text input
    const inputField = this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[1];

    //Why is this logging empty??
    console.log("The input value: ", inputField.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the bound field  sampleText ? does it has some value ? is it getting override some where ?

Comment: @VilsadPP It is bound to 'sampleText' in the TS file. I have edited my question and added the file.

Comment: thanks for the stackblitz, let me check

Comment: i was able to access the value through inputField.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model') only. value was never used along with ng-model, i don't know the theoretical explanation for that.

Comment: Thank you, although I can capture the value with ng-reflect-model, it won't work when I run Angular in production mode as ng-reflect-* attributes are disabled.

Comment: another method is you bind your directive to this input and inject ng-model in the constructor, and access the value through the injected model

Comment: Good point. It works and solves my problem. Thank you.